# I installed libboost but can't link to it

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I have installed `libboost-dev` through `apt-get`, and it's placed in `/usr/lib`.

```
/usr/lib$ ls | grep boost
libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
libboost_iostreams.so.1.46.1
libboost_serialization.so.1.46.1
libboost_system.so.1.46.1
libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
libboost_wserialization.so.1.46.1
```

But when I tried to compile a source that uses `boost_thread` I still got a error.

```
$ g++ tcp_echo.cpp -o tcp_echo -L/usr/lib -llibboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ g++ tcp_echo.cpp -o tcp_echo -L/usr/lib -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's the right way to install and link to `libboost`?

Comment: You don't need `-L/usr/lib`, it's automatically added to the library search path.

Comment: Have you tried running `ldconfig` (as root) after installing?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ldconfig is supposed to be run by apt, so he should be good.  Especially if `-L` is used anyway.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling them?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you do have no libboost_thread.so.  You have the versioned 1.46.1 file but usually libraries will create a symbolic link to the versioned copy with the undecorated name.  That might not be it but it's one thing I noticed.  (This is typically done by the installer.)

Comment: Not exactly related to the question, but are you using Asio? In that case you should also link `-lboost_system`. I would also make sure to have `libboost-thread-dev` installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> One thing I notice is that you do have no libboost_thread.so. You have
>   the versioned 1.46.1 file but usually libraries will create a symbolic
>   link to the versioned copy with the undecorated name. That might not
>   be it but it's one thing I noticed. (This is typically done by the
>   installer.) – [Omaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235584/omaha)

I think this is the point. It imply that I installed `libboost` the wrong way. In fact, I only installed `libboost-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

But what should I do is:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost1.46-doc libboost-date-time1.46-dev ibboost-filesystem1.46-dev libboost-graph1.46-dev libboost-iostreams1.46-dev libboost-math1.46-dev libboost-program-options1.46-dev libboost-python1.46-dev libboost-random1.46-dev libboost-regex1.46-dev libboost-serialization1.46-dev libboost-signals1.46-dev libboost-system1.46-dev libboost-test1.46-dev libboost-thread1.46-dev libboost-wave1.46-dev
```

(Or, in my particular case, install `libboost-system1.46-dev libboost-thread1.46-dev` at least)

And once you install them correctly, there should be `.a` and `.so` in `/usr/lib`.

```
/usr/lib$ ls | grep boost
libboost_date_time.a
libboost_date_time-mt.a
libboost_date_time-mt.so
libboost_date_time.so
libboost_date_time.so.1.46.1
libboost_filesystem.a
libboost_filesystem-mt.a
... and so on ...
```

Comment: It used to be, Ubuntu had the meta-package libboost-dev-all to install all of those. However, I can't seem to find it now. Here's a command line that might help:
`sudo apt-get install ``apt-cache search libboost | grep -- -dev | grep -v '[12]\.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $1; }'`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04, the package is named: libboost-all-dev (not libboost-dev-all)

Answer (score 1):

The comment box screwed up the quoting of this suggestion, so I'm posting it as an answer to get correct quoting.

It used to be, Ubuntu had the meta-package libboost-dev-all to install all of those. However, I can't seem to find it now. Here's a command line that might help:

```
sudo apt-get install `apt-cache search libboost | \
    grep -- -dev | \
    grep -v '[12]\.[0-9]' | \
    awk '{ print $1; }'`
```

(Taken from https://github.com/imvu-open/istatd/ file install-boost-dev.sh )

Comment: for others -- I had exactly the problem the OP had, and this command indeed instantly solved it.  ubuntu 15.10  .  Incidentally, 'libboost-dev' seems to not imply the missing 'libboost-dev-all'